# Italic feature cannot work when Chinese is input in HTMLEditor

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2

I am using JAVAFX to develop tool.
I want show Chinese italic text, but I failed. I search for the answer and I find **[it](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8117279)**. It show

> In JFX we do not synthesize font variants, thus if the given font does not support bold (or italic) the regular variant is used instead.

So, I want to konw how do I programmatically turn fonts into italic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just bundle required italic font file (.ttf or .otf) with your application.

Then load it with `Font.loadFont()` and use `-fx-font-family` or `.setFont()` where applicable.

Only remember to check the really created font name as in case of error the font creation fallbacks to "System". For example:

```
Font font = Font.font("Baltica TYGRA", FontWeight.BOLD, 20);
System.out.println(font.getName());
```

If all OK then this should output `"Baltica Bold TYGRA"`.

If the font required wasn't created and was substituted by default one, then it prints `"System Bold"` with no any exception thrown (Note also it will not print `System` even if `System` font doesn't support boldface on environment used).

---

And there is another way - you can make *slanted* text with transformation:

```
@FXML
private Text textNode;

    textNode.setText("Tattoo battle: 味噌 vs. Борщ!");
    textNode.getTransforms().add(new Shear(-0.35, 0));
```

Comment: Unluckily, there is no font support Chinese italic.

Comment: @huangjs It because of there is no Italy in China. I suppose "italique" for chinese font means the same as "calligraphic". There are many chinese calligraphic fonts and some of them are free.

Comment: @huangjs On other hand, you can make text slanted with `Transform` (fonts creators cry when see this...). I'll try it in a few minutes later.